# Proving Linearity of a Map

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to determine linearity of the following map:

\begin{align}
T \colon  \mathbb{R}^2 & \to \mathbb{R}\\
 (x,y) & \mapsto  (3x+2y)  
\end{align}

This is $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ function and I understand that I have to prove two conditions to determine linearity.

1. $ T(x+y)= T(x)+T(y)$
2. $T(cx)= cT(x)$

I have done $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ maps but not sure on how to do this one, could some please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following: Let $(x_1,y_1);(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be given. Then:
$$ T(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)=3(x_1+x_2)+2(y_1+y_2)=(3x_1+2y_1)+(3x_2+2y_2)=T(x_1,y_1)+T(x_2,y_2).$$
So, the first condition is satisfied. Consider next $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, c\in\mathbb{R}.$
$$ T(cx,cy)=3cx+2cy=c(3x+2y)=cT(x,y). $$
So, this is a linear map.